# Windows kiosk mode - Solution

Tags: windows-7, kiosk

I currently have a device running Windows 64-bit edition. I have 2 multi-touch displays attached to it. These multi-touch displays are recognized by windows as touch interfaces thus activating the Tablet PC settings and features.

Upon touching any area of the screens I get the windows pointers with a small animation behind it.

I wish to disable this pointer from appearing, as well as control and restrict some other features from Windows 7 (hiding the taskbar etc...). I really do not care about the user getting feedback about the current touch point.

Any solutions at all to make this PC run in a restricted kiosk mode?

Software [Free or paid]- Programming solutions etc... anything is welcome!

Comment: Have you considered Gnu/Linux, you can easily (all the documentation is available, it is self consistent, and modular) configure it to do what ever you want.

Comment: Thank you @richard however the application heavily relies on Windows for its infrastructure and development, and Linux is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the mouse pointer, I have used [Nomousy](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=2197) in the past for touchscreens.  It simple and works well.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/).

If you want to hide the mouse:

```
DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "ShowCursor", "int", False); hide pointer
```

If you want to lockdown the mouse further (get _BlockInputEX [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87735-blockinputex-udf/page__hl__%20blockinputex)):

```
_MouseTrap(0,0,1,1); traps in top left corner
_BlockInputEx(2); disables mouse input
```

As a note, _BlockInputEx can also restrict specified keyboard keys as well if you so desire.

In order to hide the taskbar, you can do this:

```
WinSetState("[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]", "", @SW_HIDE)
```